# Xcode can't find a valid target to run or debug

Tags: xcode, xcode15

Sorry if this sounds dumb, complete swift noob here,

I am trying to run my project suddenly it happens to me from my debugging target list  target is missing.

[image: here is Screenshot]

But when I go to general project settings in Xcode it's still showing under Targets:

[image: correct target is showing in project settings]

Comment: What do you see if you click "Manage schemes"?